# Glitch in python code when converted from C++ code?

Tags: python, c++

I'm kind of new to python, and I wonder how you would convert the following code in C++ to python

```
int kids, cd;
while (cin >> kids >> cd){
    if (kids == 0 && cd == 0)
    break;
    cout << pow(cd, kids)<<endl;
}
```

So I think it's probably something like

```
    from math import pow
    kids = int(raw_input())
    cd = int(raw_input())
    while kids!=0 and cd!=0:
       print pow(cd, kids)
       kids = int(raw_input())
       cd = int(raw_input())
```

When I submit my python code to the online judge SPOJ, I got a runtime error. My C++ code isn't accepted because of the overflow when the numbers get too large...
What's wrong?

Also when I tried to compile the python code using

http://repl.it/languages/Python

with input

```
2
5
```

and I get the output

```
25.0
```

But how do I make it to be 25 instead of 25.0?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `>>` or should that be `>=`?

Comment: @Hugh: `>>` is probably intentional; `cin >> x` reads from the standard input into `x`.

Comment: Yes, >> is intentional; on each line, there will be two variables kids and cd to be read in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code is close to, but not *quite* like the original C++ code. In C++, you exit the loop on EOF or when both of the numbers are 0. In Python, you exit only when both of the numbers are zero, failing with a runtime error on EOF. Additionally, in C++, `cin >> kids >> cd` will read `kids` and `cd` from standard input separated by whitespace, whereas your Python code reads it separated by newlines. Finally, you're using integer operations in C++, but floating-point calculations in Python.

Let's start with the EOF problem. To catch an EOF, you do a read as usual and catch the `EOFError` exception, e.g.:

```
try:
    kids = int(raw_input())
    cd   = int(raw_input())
except EOFError:
    break  # out of the loop we're in (not shown)
```

The floating-point problem is also pretty easy to solve: `pow` is not necessary; rather, Python's got an operator for it: `**`. Thus, you've got

```
print cd ** kids
```

Lastly, there's that pesky delimiter problem. How you solve this depends on how your input looks. If you've got two inputs per line, e.g.:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Then you'd want to read the line once, split it up, and convert each piece to an integer:

```
try:
    line = raw_input()
except EOFError:
    break
kids, cd = line.split()
kids = int(kids)
cd   = int(cd)
```

There are other solutions for other formats, including a direct parallel of the C++ code; but that's more complex and may not be necessary.

Lastly, consider using a `while True` loop without repeating the `kids = ...; cd = ...` code at the start and `break`ing when you want to stop, as you did in the C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    kids = int(raw_input())
    cd   = int(raw_input())
    if cd and kids:
        print(cd ** kids)
    else:
        break
```

**Edit**  after looking at http://www.spoj.com/problems/UJ/ I would suggest

```
while True:
    n,d = [int(s) for s in raw_input().split()]
    if n and d:
        print(n ** d)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, Hugh Bothwell. But your code still gives run time error for some reasons when I submitted it on the online judge SPOJ.

Comment: Here's the details: 
<br>
number status signal time memory
test 0 runtime error -1 0.03s 3740KB
</br>

Comment: @user3213711: which SPOJ problem?